# Detect data table mismatches when NA's in joined table

Tags: r, join, data.table

When joining two data tables, mismatches can either be dropped, or show as `NA` values. But if there's `NA` values in the joined table, these can't be detected.

Sample data:

```r
d1 = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(5,4,3,2))
setDT(d1) ; setkey(d1, x)
d2 = data.frame(x=c(1,2,4),z=c(1,2,NA))
setDT(d2) ; setkey(d2, x)
```

giving:

```
> d1
   x y
1: 1 5
2: 2 4
3: 3 3
4: 4 2
> d2
   x  z
1: 1  1
2: 2  2
3: 4 NA
```

Now I want to join `d2` onto `d1`. This is the usual left-join but I can't tell if row 3 and row 4 column `z` is NA because it didn't match (`d2$x` has no 3) or because there was a match and the `z` was `NA` (`d2$z` is `NA` for `d2$x==4`):

```r
> d2[d1]
   x  z y
1: 1  1 5
2: 2  2 4
3: 3 NA 3
4: 4 NA 2
```

There's ugly ways of doing this:

```
> d2$match=TRUE
> d2[d1]
   x  z match y
1: 1  1  TRUE 5
2: 2  2  TRUE 4
3: 3 NA    NA 3
4: 4 NA  TRUE 2
```

and now I can use the `$match` column to test if it matched or not. But my gut tells me this is ugly and there may be a better way, short of not using this syntax and doing a `match(d1$x, d2$x)` instead.

If the join syntax could keep the `$x` value from both sides of the join, that would work since it would be `NA` for the mismatched rows. Is there a way to keep "`x.i`" and "`x.j`"?
`dplyr::left_join` has a `keep=TRUE` argument that does this:

`

```
> left_join(d1, d2, keep=TRUE)
Joining with `by = join_by(x)`
   x.x y x.y  z
1:   1 5   1  1
2:   2 4   2  2
3:   3 3  NA NA
4:   4 2   4 NA
```

`

Then I can reliably split this on `$x.y` to get matches and mismatches.

Comment: I kinda like the `match = TRUE` approach. Seems clear and simple.

Comment: You can mimic the behavior of `keep=TRUE` with `d2[,x2:=x][d1]`, making a copy of one of the join keys. I don't know that that's any better, but it is datatable-native.

Comment: @r2evans one problem with that is you've now added an `x2` column to `d2`, and maybe it already had an `x2` column, and since data table does things by reference you can't do that in a subroutine without stomping on the `d2` that the caller has. Creating a column with `d2$match=TRUE` has similar problems with name uniqueness but won't modify `d2` in a subroutine...

Comment: In `data.table` you can use `d2[d1, .(i.x, y, x.x, z)]` or `d2[d1, .(x, y, x.x, z)]` to achieve the same results as using `dyplr`'s `left_join` with `keep = T`. I like your match approach though.

Comment: @Spacedman, you don't like how my approach added a column, yet you suggested `d2$match=TRUE`. How is that any better? I guess I should retract my suggestion; while it mimics the `keep=T` behavior, it doesn't add much to your `$match` method.

Comment: As I say adding with `d2$match=` also adds a column, but it won't create a side effect if I'm doing the join inside a function. `(function(A, B){B[,x2:=x][A]})(d1, d2)` modifies `d2`, but `(function(A, B){B$x2=TRUE;B[A]})(d1, d2)` doesn't. I'm trying to code cleanly without side effects and without adding columns with names that might stomp on existing columns (which is why my column-adding solution irks me too).

Comment: `d2[d1, .(x, z, match = !is.na(x.x), y)]`

Comment: @Spacedman While you technically don't have side-effect, this code does copy `d2` into a new version of `B`. I'm not opposed to this action (I'm using R, after all), but it does tend to go against one common premise of using `data.table`: referential semantics. Is that intentional or at least an accepted by-product of this method? If this mismatch-join is intended to work with larger tables, the action of copying the data may not be desirable.

Comment: If people would like to post answers in answers instead of one-liners we need to debate in comments, then maybe I'll be able to make  decision on the "best".